# .htaccess - Block or redirect direct URL access to folder/files

Tags: .htaccess, url, localhost

I've a website and i'm trying to block direct access to 2 specific folders and inside files, except for internal requests. I already tried using: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`, `RedirectMatch` and `Deny/Allow` rules.

They work fine blocking the direct access but local requests are blocked too and trying to put "localhost","127.0.0.1" or "127.0.0.1::1" as an exception doesn't work, so the result is that my index page can't access essential files like main CSS.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to block access to the folder containing css then you will not have access to it. css files are fetched by the browser and need to be accessible

Comment: Set up a different virtual host for localhost in your web server configuration.

Comment: @NikolaLukic No, that doesn't help me.

Comment: @JoshKisb I want that my index can reach that css file but the others can't with the direct url.

Comment: @RolandWeber Can't do it, i bought this host, i don't have that power.

Comment: if you use url in index then that means it needs direct access. for example `<link href="css/main.css">` the browser will fetch main.css from the url directly when it encounters that line

Comment: @JoshKisb I see, so isn't a request from localhost but from visitor IP. Any alternative?